# Can I use Enrollment on Arrival for Global Entry if I have an interview scheduled at some other office?

Tags: global-entry

Can I use Enrollment on Arrival for Global Entry if I have an interview scheduled at some other office?

I have a Global Entry interview scheduled at an office "near" my home. It is a couple of months in the future. I also have a trip planned where I reenter via an airline flight which originates from a pre-clearance site, and the pre-clearance site is among the places that Enrollment on Arrival is said to be available.

Feel free to comment on the "should I use Enrollment on Arrival" aspect of this question.

Comment: If you're at a pre-clearance site, and it's a Canadian airport, it's a pity you didn't apply for NEXUS instead of GlobalEntry.  It's half the price, and works in both countries, and includes all GE benefits.  (I have NEXUS.)

Comment: Your point is well taken. I was hoping that I'd have it done before that, and I tried to start early enough. I REALLLY want it for my Argentina-Uruguay-Falklands-Antarctica trip and thereafter.

Comment: Another strategy is to frequently (several times a day) to check the website to see if earlier appointment slots have opened.  I got an appointment within a few days using this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people in [this FlyerTalk thread](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trusted-travelers/1853696-global-entry-enrollment-arrival.html) seem to have done it with an appointment already scheduled elsewhere, and nobody mentioned anything about being sent away due to the existing appointment. That's about as official a source as I'm aware of.

Doesn't seem like there could be any harm in going to the Enrollment on Arrival desk at preclearence and asking. Worst case should be that they see you have an appointment and tell you to come back then. It does sound like there can sometimes be a wait, since there are limited queues that handle the process, so probably good to allow some extra time, or skip it if it's going to take too long.

Comment: This answer and the FlyerTalk link seem to cover all the bases. (1) You can (2) You should if there's no line (3) There definitely could be a line